# PHP Deep Object Copy/Clone

Tags: php

What is the best accepted way in PHP to perform a **deep** object copy/clone?

I have found some examples using serialize which i think suffers from some issues.

Comment: I was going to point you to the documentation - but then I realized - I do not even know when cloning is "deep".

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking. You mention cloning yet the second sentence mentions serialization. What exactly are you interested in? What is the best way to serialize a cloned object?

Comment: Have you already read [Object Cloning](http://php.net/language.oop5.cloning)?

Comment: Here is a better question: why do you think that you need it ?

Comment: @tereško - amongst other things, i have on object in which one of the properties holds an array of objects.

Comment: This question is **not** a duplicate. This question is about **deep copy**, not simply `clone`

Comment: "i have on object in which one of the properties holds an array of objects." No, you misunderstand how PHP stores references to objects. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have full access to your classes, you can implement `__clone()` in all of them and then use the `clone` keyword. Otherwise the `clone` keyword will just create a shallow copy of the topmost object, while potential references within this object will continue to point at their original targets. The `__clone()` method also gives you more control, but may create endless loops with cyclic references, if you don't deal with them explicitly.

The serialization technique generally works, does not die on cyclic references, but is more expensive in terms of memory and CPU.

Comment: Ok thanks, i had read on a couple of blogs that there can be issues with the serialization techniques i.e. it does cover some edge cases (not massively important for my specific use case though it got me interested in if there was a 'best way' to do thi)

Comment: As the serialization is basically just a trick, the `__clone()` method can be considered the "right way" to do it. Depends on the use case though, if it's necessary to do it the right way ;-)

Comment: Great, didn't think about using the serialization trick. Quite silly that the question has been closed.